# Why do I get `404 File not found` (through Jena) during Virtuoso checkpoint?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, virtuoso

We have a Java app that calls Virtuoso. If it runs some SPARQL query while Virtuoso does a checkpoint, it gives: `"com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryExceptionHTTP: File not found"`

My first thought was because `CheckpointSyncMode=2`, it blocks the query. But I managed to get this exception when `CheckpointSyncMode=1`.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to copy more code than the method call; but I can reproduce it with any SPARQL query.

```
ResponseResult resultsAndBindings = APIEndpointUtil.call(req, nb, match, contextPath, queryParams);
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
HttpException: 404 File not found
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execCommon(HttpQuery.java:446)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execPost(HttpQuery.java:344)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:239)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:302)
at com.epimorphics.lda.sources.SourceBase.executeSelect(SourceBase.java:110)
at com.epimorphics.lda.query.APIQuery.requestTotalCount(APIQuery.java:917)
at com.epimorphics.lda.core.APIEndpointImpl.call_revised(APIEndpointImpl.java:112)
at com.epimorphics.lda.core.APIEndpointImpl.call(APIEndpointImpl.java:92)
at com.epimorphics.lda.core.APIEndpointUtil.call(APIEndpointUtil.java:53)
```

REPRODUCE in a very simple test environment:

I set up an empty Virtuoso instance:

```
OpenLink Virtuoso Server
Version 07.20.3215-pthreads for Linux as of Jan 20 2016"
```

`CheckpointSyncMode=2` or `CheckpointSyncMode=1` doesn't matter; it happens anyway.

Make sure Virtuoso is busy with checkpoint:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    isql-vt 1111 dba dba exec="checkpoint;"
done;
```

Call the endpoint with Jena (with: `com.epimorphics.lda:elda-lda:1.3.16`, `jena-core:2.10.1`):

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        while(true)
            getPreviousSnapshot();
    }

    public static void getPreviousSnapshot() {

        ParameterizedSparqlString pss = new ParameterizedSparqlString("SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE {  GRAPH ?g {    ?s ?p ?o  }}");

        System.out.println("Executing SPARQL query:" + pss.toString());

        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://33.33.33.11:8890/sparql", pss.asQuery());
        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();

        processResultSet(resultSet);
        qe.close();

    }

    private static void processResultSet(com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results) {

        while (results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution qs = results.next();
            String s = qs.getResource("g").toString();
            System.out.println(s);

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Executing SPARQL query:SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE {  GRAPH ?g {    ?s ?p ?o  }}
http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#
http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#
http://localhost:8890/sparql
http://localhost:8890/DAV/
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
Executing SPARQL query:SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE {  GRAPH ?g {    ?s ?p ?o  }}
Exception in thread "main" HttpException: 404 File not found
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execCommon(HttpQuery.java:446)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:289)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:240)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:302)
    at Main.getPreviousSnapshot(Main.java:21)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: Without seeing the whole code where you call it and the error stack trace, impossible to help...

Comment: thank you for the feedback, updated the question.

Comment: The error says "HttpException: 404 File not found";  I'd guess that you've got the wrong endpoint URI.  Without more code, it's impossible to say, though.

Comment: Still some question remain: Does it work with some other SPARQL queries. I can see from the code that you use the ELDA - Linked Data API. What URL do you use for the endpoint (just in case if this works never). Or does it mean that it works until you resp. Virtuoso does a checkpoint?

Comment: [`CheckpointSyncMode` docs](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/dbadm/#ini_parameters_checkpointsyncmode) suggest it's irrelevant here. (Apparently) Virtuoso-specific questions are often better raised to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: My employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: added very simple test to reproduce, I hope now everything is included. @TallTed: I sent an email to Virtuoso mailing list 4 days ago, still waits for moderator approval.. OpenLink Forums can not be read with fresh registration.. Support case keeps showing a popup window to log in (but if I go to another page from same window it shows my username in top right as logged in user)

Comment: @BalazsVarhegyi - Hmm. I've nudged the mailing list moderators. The forums are certainly readable without any login; posting requires login and/or user verification. Support Case system is distinct from other systems; please email support@openlinksw.com if you still can't get in!

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but I do notice you're running a [several-month-old Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews#2016-04-24%20-%20Virtuoso%207.2.4%20Released,%20Open%20Source%20and%20Commercial%20Editions), and wonder about your versions of Jena, [Virtuoso Jena Provider, and Virtuoso JDBC Driver](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider).

Comment: @TallTed, thank you. Added jena version (2.10.1) to the question as well. Yes, I didn't tested on latest release yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer I got on virtuoso mailing list: Jena gets no connection to the SPARQL service at the time Virtuoso is temporarily inaccessible due to performing a checkpoint (which is an atomic action in Virtuoso) and thus simply returns a 404 error.